# Getting "Permission Denied" when trying to install node.js canvas on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, node-canvas

i am using canvas package for node.js

it works fine on my pc but whenever i deploy it to heroku i always get an error
here is what i get

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:
remote:        > canvas@2.6.1 install /tmp/build_f373ac33/node_modules/canvas
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.bcUNy/_logs/2020-08-06T17_57_03_074Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
```

i tried this tutorial but it didnt work
https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation%3A-Heroku

here's my package.json

````
  "name": "asta-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a discord bot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "hello"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.3.x",
    "npm": "*"
  },
  "author": "reuben chagas fernandes",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cleverbot-node": "^0.3.11",
    "decode-encode-binary": "^1.4.9",
    "didyoumean": "^1.2.1",
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "ffmpeg": "^0.0.4",
    "google-tts-api": "0.0.4",
    "mal-scraper": "^2.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "opusscript": "^0.0.7",
    "pg": "^8.0.2",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "simple-youtube-api": "^5.2.1",
    "translate": "^1.1.2",
    "trivia-api": "^1.0.1",
    "urban-dictionary": "^2.2.1",
    "weather-js": "^2.0.0",
    "wikifakt": "^1.0.3",
    "wikijs": "^6.0.1",
    "youtube-search": "^1.1.4",
    "ytdl-core": "^2.0.1"
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well some versions of node-canvas dont work on heroku
the canvas version im using is 2.6.1
and node version is 13.3.0

the build fails on other node version
it works perfectly on 13.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

Comment: i still get build failed

Comment: Please post your package.json file too.

Comment: what does this do? Can you add explanation

Answer (score 0):

Was experiencing the issue on node v16.

Was installing the canvas package.

Helped: installing node v13 (nvm install 13 && nvm use 13)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN I didn't use Heroku, so i assumed i may add a bit of clarity to that.